# repeat program function failure in C, scanf related?

Tags: c, function, scanf, repeat, do-while

So I'm trying to ask the user if they would like to repeat my program and I am getting a weird result now and then. It doesn't happen everytime and I havn't been able to figure out what triggers it.

To me it looks like it is assigning the 'return' after I enter 'q' to repeatProgram instead of the 'q' but I have no Idea why.

The output when it works:

*to exit enter q, to continue enter y.*
s
*you've entered s, that isn't a valid option.*

The output when it fails:

*to exit enter q, to continue enter y.*
q
*you've entered*
*, that isn't a valid option.*

The code:

```
char RepeatProgramPrompt()
{
    char repeatProgram;

    do
    {
        printf("\nTo exit enter q, to continue enter y.\n");
        scanf("%c%*c", &repeatProgram);

        repeatProgram = tolower(repeatProgram);

        if(repeatProgram != 'y' && repeatProgram != 'q')
        {
            printf("\nYou've entered %c, that isn't a valid option.\n", repeatProgram);

        }

    }while(repeatProgram != 'y' && repeatProgram != 'q');


    return(repeatProgram);
}
```

So my question is, why is this happening? it will work fine for a bunch of tries and then just fail.

Sorry if I've formatted this wrong it is my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That problem occurs because your `scanf` reads the `\n` after your first input. To avoid this change your `scanf` statement to this:

```
scanf("%c", &repeatProgram);
getchar(); // this will remove the excess '\n'
```

**Output:**

```
Sukhvir@Sukhvir-PC ~
$ ./test

To exit enter q, to continue enter y.
d

You've entered d, that isn't a valid option.

To exit enter q, to continue enter y.
s

You've entered s, that isn't a valid option.

To exit enter q, to continue enter y.
d

You've entered d, that isn't a valid option.

To exit enter q, to continue enter y.
q

Sukhvir@Sukhvir-PC ~
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Eat up the trailing whitespace characters with newline after scanf and it should work:

```
scanf("%c", &repeatProgram);
while(getchar() != '\n')
{
    //do nothing
}
```

Sample [output](http://ideone.com/RLLpPm).