# C - for loop only execute ones after scanf

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

The `for` loop runs only once, after entering my answer with `scanf`, the `for` loop terminates. I have no idea why?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){  
    char answer;  
    gotoxy(32,10);  //self-made function(using Dev C++) to go to a coordinate
    star_vowels(easy[i]);    
    gotoxy(30,18);  
    printf("ANSWER: ");  
    scanf("%s", &answer);  
}
```

Comment: You mentioned the format specifier for scanf to be %s. It should be %c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **answer** variable is defined as character so you should change the format string of the scanf function:

```
scanf("%c",&answer);
```

Comment: I feel so embarrassed right now. This actually fixed it, tho my for loop doesn't count by 1. It's kind of skipping an array index after the other.

Comment: @IvanRalphG.Vitto: Regarding the "skipping": do you see `ANSWER: ` printed multiple times even though you have entered only one number? [That may be because `scanf` consumes the newline.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628381/repeat-program-function-failure-in-c-scanf-related).

Comment: @DarkDust I don't see it print multiple times because of the gotoxy(), however I tried printing out the value of the current array that's why I knew that my for loop is skipping one after the other. Any solutions to this?

Comment: @IvanRalphG.Vitto: I don't really get that, sorry. Use something like `printf("%d\n", i);` to really check whether `i` is skipping values. Or better yet: use a debugger :-)

Comment: @DarkDust I've already tried that. It sure is skipping depending on the length of whatever I type plus 1 character for the new line.

Comment: @IvanRalphG.Vitto: But for you **answer** variable must be a string or a char?

Comment: @klyone yes of course. It's solved by the way, thanks to you guys! Solved it by replacing scanf with gets();. Thanks again!

Comment: @IvanRalphG.Vitto But be careful because the gets() function gets a string and you try to store in a char variable... I think you should have the same problem...

Comment: @klyone will do, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely because of your buffer overflow.

You define a variable `answer` that can store just one `char`. Yet you pass it to `scanf` to scan a *string*. If you just enter one character and press enter, you already overflow `answer` and likely overwrite `i` in the process which then becomes larger than or equal to 10.

You need to pass a buffer (like `char answer[100];` or dynamically allocated with `malloc`) to `scarf`. [Using `scanf` to scan a string correctly is a bit tricky.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)

If you really only meant to read a single character instead, @klyone's answer is the correct one: use the `%c` format string.

Answer (score 0):

One issue would be that you are using scanf to input a string, however answer is a single character.

Even if you are only entering a single character string, it will be attempting to put that character in the string, followed by a null byte.

Assuming a 1 charcater answer, changing the 'char answer' to 'char answer[2];' and changing the scanf() to scanf("%1s", answer); may help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to read in a string as opposed to a single character, I would highly recommend using [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead of `scanf` to read your input, as it will ensure that you never get a buffer overflow of any sort, as far as I recall.

Also, as others have said, you will first need to allocate more than one character for the answer, either by statically allocating it or doing it dynamically with `malloc` and `free`. Assuming you want to save the answers somewhere, doing dynamic allocations would be necessary. If you only need it one time, allocating it statically like `char answer[100];` would suffice. Although I would recommend putting something like `#define BUFFER 100` at the top of your file, and allocating it like `char answer[BUFFER];` instead.